# Cannot create named pipe

Tags: c++

i am trying to communicate beween c++ module and c# module using namedpipe
in my code

```
_pipe = CreateFile(
    pipeName.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ, // only need read access
    FILE_SHARE_READ ,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS ,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);

if(_pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    int i = 5;
}
```

i am always getting error 2 when i try to create the pipe  using

```
listener = new PipeListener("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a named pipe in C++ you need to use CreateNamedPipe. To connect to a created pipe you can use CreateFile / CallNamedPipe. Check out [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)